# Running into problems with mobile vs desktop styling

Tags: html, css, inline, word-wrap, inline-styles

I want to include the logos of each of my portfolio pages wrapped to the right in the text. I was able to accomplish this on desktop using inline HTML to float it right:

```
<p><a href="link" style="padding: 0 0px; float: right;" src="img" alt="" 
width="200" height="200" /></a></p>
<h4><strong>Amazin' Aces Pickleball</strong></h4>
```

Here is the link: http://matzniewski.com/my-work/amazin-aces/

This is what it looks like on mobile:

[image]

How can I get it so the logo sits on top of the title on mobile so they aren't scrunched together?

I figured I'm going to have to go into the CSS but I've been messing around with different commands within my

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
```

and can't figure out how to get it right.

I am using Wordpress and SiteOrigin, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use Media Queries to adjust your float property.

```
.widget img {
    height: auto
}

@media screen and (min-width:831px) {
    .widget img {
        float: right;
     }
}

@media screen and (max-width:830px) {
        .widget img {
            float: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: I should note, I believe that OP wants float:none; for min-width and float:right for max width. Still think you deserve the upvote I gave as all the correct pieces are there.